# List of Lego Technic sets with remote controller?

Tags: technic, remote-control

I am interested in buying a set with motors (etc) with a remote controller.

Is there a website that allows to search with this conditions? Official website is pretty bad.

I have found the Lego Technic 9398 4x4 until now: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjlo7G661Iw

Are there any other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There have been many remote controlled Technic sets over the years. I've organized this list with the most recent generations of remote control elements first.

## Control+

Current remote controlled Technic sets will contain a Control+ hub. We can find them by showing the [sets that contain that part](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=bb0961c01&in=S) on Bricklink.

## Power Functions

For Power Functions, we can look for [sets containing the Power Functions IR Receiver](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=58123c01) and [sets containing the PF IR Receiver V2](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=58123bc01). It looks like the following sets contain that part and are remote controlled:

- Motorized Bulldozer 8275
- Motorized Excavator 8043
- 4x4 Crawler 9398
- 4x4 Crawler Exclusive Edition 41999
- 6x6 All Terrain Tow Truck 42070
- Volvo L350F Wheel Loader 42030
- RC Tracked Racer 42065
- Remote-Controlled Stunt Racer 42095

## RC

Prior to Power Functions, there were dedicated RC elements used to provide remote control functionality to sets. These can be found in [this category](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=179.158) on Bricklink. Most of those sets aren't really Technic, but some are. For proper Technic sets, it's probably helpful to look at just the RC sets containing a separate [buggy motor](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=5292&in=S) instead of the large integrated vehicle base. Those three sets are:

- Hot Flame 8376
- RC Race Buggy 8475
- Supersonic RC 8366

Comment: 42065 - it runs off IR receiver too, different "mold" or whatever according to bricklink: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=58123c01&colorID=86&in=A

Comment: @htmlcoderexe Thanks! I've added that one and some other sets releases since 2013 (when I first posted this answer). If there are any others missing, feel free to make edits.

Comment: None of the following sets seems to be present on a list: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=179.158

Comment: Indeed. None of the new Control+ sets are present either. I'll make some adjustments.

Comment: 8183 and 8184 might need to be added under PF. While they don't use the usual receivers and battery boxes, they are still controlled by the same PF Controller. So technically, these are PF enabled sets, just with a different base.

Comment: @Alex I don't think those qualify as Technic sets

Comment: My bad, I thought question was about remote controlled sets in general.

Comment: @jncraton oh, just noticed the date, haha. Glad I could help, would you prefer I made edits directly next time?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe No worries. This answer needed a lot of updating, and I appreciate you bringing it to my attention. Helpful edits are always great. We're a collaborative community, and improving each other's answers is a big part of that.

Comment: @Alex Not a problem. My original answer did include trains for some reason, so I can understand the confusion. I've reworked the RC section to pull out just the Technic sets, as many of the sets that used the integrated base aren't Technic sets either.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Power Functions and Control+, there is also Lego Mindstorms. The EV3 generation includes a remote control, and you can also make block-based programs for your robots if using the remote isn't suitable.